# Thread a function over a list and with a non-atomic 2nd parameter?

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

From the documentation, Thread's behavior on functions where the first parameter is a List and the second is an atomic expression, is this:

```
Thread[f[{a, b, c}, x]] 

(* {f[a, x], f[b, x], f[c, x]} *)
```

If the second argument of 'f' is not atomic, it is possible to thread over its first argument {a,b,c} while treating the 2nd argument as if it were atomic? For example, consider:

```
M = Table[i + j, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 2}]

(* {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}} *)
```

Then,

```
Thread[f[{a, b, c}, M]]

(* {f[a, {2, 3}], f[b, {3, 4}], f[c, {4, 5}]} *)
```

This is understandable because M is not atomic so For example:

```
g[p_, M_ /; Dimensions[M] == {3, 2}] := {p, M}
```

Threading over `g` Doesn't work as intended:

```
Thread[g[{a, b, c}, M]]

(* {{a, {2, 3}}, {b, {3, 4}}, {c, {4, 5}}} *)
```

Worse still, the result above is due to a coincidence: Length@M==3. If this is not the case, Thread returns an error:

```
Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in f[{a,b,c},{{2,3,4,5},{3,4,5,6}}] cannot be combined. >>
```

I've also considered wrapping M in some variation of Hold, but none yield atomic expressions. Is there a way to force Thread to treat the 2nd argument of the function as atomic?

The ultimate goal is to `SetAttributes` of the function to `Listable`.

Comment: But ... what is your intended result? ... `f[#, M] & /@ {a, b, c}` ?

Comment: @Verde, it should handle both f[#, M] & /@ {a, b, c} and f[#,M]& @ a.

Comment: I'm really not quite sure what you are trying to achieve but doesn't `ReleaseHold@Thread[f[{a, b, c}, Hold@M]]` do what you want?

Comment: @sebhofer, your approach does solve it if Thread is called directly, but as described in the last part of the question and in the response to Verde's comment, the idea is to make the function Listable. Try SetAttributes[f, Listable] and then f[{a, b, c}, M] and f[{a, b, c}, Hold@M]. Is there workaround to this?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, I gave explicit solutions [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node401.html) and [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node425.html), where I also explain the solutions in detail.

Comment: So you want the described functionality but without using any additional functions like `Thread`...?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard can I edit the title to include Listable?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The question does not strike me as being asked narrowly about `Thread`. The goal seems to thread a function over a list in a certain way, and `Thread` was just used as a seemingly most straightforward way to obtain the desired result. At least, this is how I interpreted it from the start.

Comment: Alan I respect Leonid's opinion.  I have amended my answer to address that aspect of the question.

Comment: Alan, I see that you have not Accepted an answer to this question.  I believe you were going to Accept Leonid's as soon as you checked it.  Did you forget or was it unsatisfactory?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I haven't yet but thanks for the reminder. I'll try to test by this weekend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will reproduce two solutions from my book, one using `Listable` `SubValues` described [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node401.html):

```
listThread[f_, x_, y_] :=
  Module[{auxf},
   SetAttributes[auxf, Listable];
   auxf[t_][z_] := f[t, z];
   Through[auxf[x][y]]];
```

and another one using pure functions with `Listable` attribute, described [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node425.html):

```
halfListable[f_, x_, y_] := Function[t, f[t, y], Listable][x]
```

Here is an example:

```
listThread[f, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}]
halfListable[f, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}]

(*
   {f[1, {3, 4, 5}], f[2, {3, 4, 5}]}
   {f[1, {3, 4, 5}], f[2, {3, 4, 5}]}
*)
```

More explanations can be found in the linked sections of the book.

Comment: Thank you Leonid - so far this looks like the best hope, I will likely accept shortly (still looking through your web site) though I was hoping to avoid custom functions. Could WRI have implemented a Level option functionality for Listable to achieve this?

Comment: @alancalvitti The probem is that `Listable` is an attribute, not a function. As such, it is wired quite deeply into the evaluation sequence. And evaluator does not have any tuning parameters, it is not even clear how you can define such parameters locally (so that they will apply to a specific head in a given place of code).

Comment: @alancalvitti Thanks for the accept. It's been a while :-).

Answer (score 7):

Does this work as desired?

```
Thread[Unevaluated[f[{a, b, c}, M]]]
```

> ```
> {f[a, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}],
>  f[b, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}], 
>  f[c, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}]}
> ```

---

Since apparently I was just being obstinate regarding the focus of this question I shall give in and address the extension of this behavior to a pseudo-Listable function.  I still find the question underspecified in that interpretation.

```
ClearAll[f, a, b, c, m]

SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]
x : f[___, _List, ___] := Thread@Unevaluated@x
f[other___] := {other}
```

Now:

```
m = Table[i + j, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 2}];

f[{a, b, c}, m]

f[m, {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {{a, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}}, {b, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}}, {c, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}}}
>
> {{{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}, a}, {{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}, b}, {{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}, c}}
> ```

Comment: Nicer than my suggestion (actually the correct way to do it) but I don't think it will satisfy the OP

Comment: @sebhofer Thanks; why not?

Comment: If I understand correctly the OP wants a function with `Listable` which does exactly this without using `Thread` or such... That's what I gather from the comment above. Not totally sure though.

Comment: @sebhofer Then a new question is required as this one is *clearly* about `Thread`.  (Final line notwithstanding.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, on my MMA 8.0.4, Thread[Unevaluated[f[{a, b, c}, M]]] evaluates to an expression that begins with: {{{f[a,2],f[a,3]},... Can anyone duplicate this?

Comment: @alancalvitti since this question so predominantly addressed `Thread` I think a new one specifically addressing `Listable` behavior is appropriate.  I am surprised by the v8 result; have you tried restarting *Mathematica* to be certain of the behavior?

Comment: @alancalvitti It does so if `f` is `Listable`, otherwise it returns the desired result.

Comment: @sebhofer, and Mr.Wizard - agreed, I just restarted and replicated your answer (without Listable attribute)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I could not get the version using Unevaluated to work on lists with this function: f2[p_, data_] := Select[data, #[[1]] == p &] (after setting attributes as you did) and the same matrix m as above. f2[2,m] and f2[3,m] work, but f2[{2, 3}, m] gives {}. ?

Comment: Same problem as above occurs when using ReleaseHold@Thread@Hold in lieu of Thread@Unevaluated

Comment: @alancalvitti with this definition: `ClearAll[f2, m];
SetAttributes[f2, HoldAll];
x : f2[___, _List, ___] := Thread@Unevaluated@x;
f2[p_, data_] := Select[data, #[[1]] == p &];
m = Table[i + j, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 2}];` this input: `f2[{2, 3}, m]` gives output: `{{{2, 3}}, {{3, 4}}}` -- I'll be in Chat for a while if you want to talk about this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, indeed it works. The next challenge is to generalize when the data matrix m has a "frame" column headers consisting of lists (eg, {2012,08,27}) rather than Strings. I posted a similar comment to kguler's solution above. I'll be happy to chat sometime.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
ClearAll[f];
Thread[f[{a, b, c}, M], List, 1]
(* {f[a, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}], f[b, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}], 
   f[c, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}]}*)


Thread[g[{a, b, c}, M], List, 1]  // Grid
```

> [image]

More related examples in `Scope >> Sequence Specifications` in [`docs >> Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html)

Comment: +1 because this is useful information and the question is not well defined, but I interpret that the solution should also handle `f[M, {a, b, c}]` and this, as written, does not.

Comment: I am mistaken, it does! `Thread[f[M, {a, b, c}], List, {2}]` (For some reason I didn't think that worked.)

Comment: Very nice. Is there any way to make Listable work with these options?

Comment: @alancalvitti, in effect you want to change the behavior of the attribute `Listable` to thread over selected arguments? I would defer to Leonid/Rojo/... on whether this is possible/advisable:)

Comment: alan, btw just noticed that @Leonid's answer and comment already adresses this question.

Comment: @kguler, I can't get the desired behavior with the following function: SelectInFrame[h_, data_] := Select[data, #[[1]] == h &]. Using the same M, Thread[SelectInFrame[2, M], List, 1] --> {{2}, {3}} (it should be {2,3}) and Thread[SelectInFrame[{2, 3}, M], List, 1] returns error: "Thread::tpos: Cannot thread over positions 1 through 1 in {}". ?

Comment: `Thread` evaluates the whole expression before threading. You need to use `Unevaluated` to prevent this behavior. So, `Thread[Unevaluated@SelectInFrame[2, M], List, 1]` gives `{{2,3}}` and `Thread[Unevaluated@SelectInFrame[{2, 3}, M], List, 1]` gives `{{{2, 3}}, {{3, 4}}}`.

Comment: @kguler, can you extend this answer if the first column of M contains Lists, eg {2012,8,25} rather than Strings? I find that it works if the last argument to Thread is {2} to match a single such list, but doesn't match lists of lists, eg {{2012,8,25},{2012,8,27}} (assuming M contains  those).

Comment: @alan, can you give the examples of `M` and `Thread` usage mentioned in your comment where `Thread[...,{2}]` works/does not work? Is `M` something like `m2 = {{{2007, 1, 30}, 3, "x"}, {{2008, 2, 23}, 4, "y"}, {{2009, 10, 14}, 5, "z"}}`?

Comment: @kguler, yes, only the 1st row or 1st column (part of the "frame") elements are changed from String to List as you show - the remaining elements can stay numbers or anything else. I describe this issue more in my own answer to the question here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/emulating-r-data-frame-getters-with-upvalues

Comment: @alan, I am not sure if this answers the question in your comment: with `m2` as above, `Thread[Unevaluated@
  SelectInFrame[{{2008, 2, 23}, DateList[{2009, 10, 14}][[;; 3]]},  m2], List, 1]` gives `{{{{2008, 2, 23}, 4, "y"}}, {{{2009, 10, 14}, 5, "z"}}}`.

Comment: @kguler, that works on lists of dates but not singletons (Thread[Unevaluated@SelectInFrame[{2007, 1, 30}, m2], List, 1] --> {{}, {}, {}} ) . The purpose of this Thread construction is to selectively map on lists but also on singleton arguments

Comment: @kguler, ... I'm trying to emulate this function using Thread: MapIfList[f_, x_] := If[Length[x] > 0, Map[f, x], f[x]]

Answer (score 2):

The following works when f is Listable and has a definition.

```
M = Table[i + j, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 2}];
SetAttributes[f,Listable]  
f[x_,y_]:={x,y}   
f[{a,b,c},Unevaluated@M]
```