# Unwanted hold in recursive function

Tags: recursion

I have a function (let it be called f) that does something useful for me and I want to be able to apply it to the elements of a list regardless of their depth and keep the list structure. For example I want to write

```
F[{{a,b},{c}}]
```

and get

```
{{f(a),f(b)},{f(c)}}
```

So my idea was to use Thread to move down one level of the list each time. So I wrote

```
F[mat_] := If[mat[[0]] === List, Thread[F[mat]], f[mat]]
```

But the result I get

```
If[Hold[Evaluate[{{a, b}, {c}}[[0]] === List]], 
    Thread[F[{{a, b}, {c}}]], f[{{a, b}, {c}}]]
```

after of course the recursion depth was reached.

So I actually have 2 question. Is there any way to do that with a built-in mathematica function. How can I avoid getting this hold? Evaluate doesn't work.

EDIT: As pointed by Rojo my problem is solved by adding Listable to the attributes of f. However I would like to know why my code does not work. How can I get rid of the hold?

Comment: What you are asking for sounds like an application of `Map`--but note that (when applied with a third argument of `{-1}`) it will produce `{{f[a], f[b]}, {f[c]}}` rather than `{{f(a),f(b)},{f(c)}}`.

Comment: Your single example doesn't remove all ambiguities. But it seems like you are looking to a `Listable` version of `f`. `SetAttributes[F, Listable];F[args___]:=f[args]`;

Comment: @whuber thanks, it works, I meant f[] instead of f().

Comment: @Rojo adding Listable to the attributes of f is exactly what I need. Thank you too.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Simple: `x = f[x]`, where `f` is any function, produces infinite recursion. `x -> f[x] -> f[f[x]] -> f[f[f[x]]]`, and so forth.

Comment: The problem you have is because `Thread` evaluates its arguments, which leads to the picture described by @OleksandrR. This will work: `F[mat_] := If[mat[[0]] === List, Thread[Unevaluated@F[mat]], f[mat]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution to your problem is indeed to give `f` the `Listable` attribute. This threads `f` automatically over lists when they are given as arguments

```
SetAttributes[f, {Listable}];
f[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]

(* {{f[a], f[b]}, {f[c], f[d]}} *)
```

To understand why your approach does not work you would have to study the *Mathematica* evaluation process carefully. Let's see whether I can explain understandably what goes wrong in your definition of `F`. First we assume, that you have a very very deeply nested list as argument and therefore your `If` will go the `True` path for quite some time. This reduces your definition to

```
F[mat_] := Thread[F[mat]]
```

You assumed now that the right part just takes the `F` and threads it inside the list. With this you would have reduced your nesting by one. This does not happen. The reason is, that `Thread` has no special evaluation attribute like `HoldFirst`. Therefore, it uses *standard evaluation*.

Let us construct a small example, where you see what this means by defining two symbols

```
func := (Print["func"]; func1);
arg := (Print["arg"]; arg1);
```

No magic happens here, the only thing you have to know is, that the moment `func` is evaluated, it first prints "func" and then returns `func1`. The definition of `arg` is equivalent. The question is now, what happens if you call

```
func[arg]
```

Think before executing it and think after you saw what happened. This reveals a small part of the evaluation process: First, the head which is `func` is evaluated and after that all (in this case only one) parameters are evaluated. What you get is `func1[arg1]`.

And now think about, what happens in the body of your function `F`. You call `F` with `{{a,b},{c,d}}` and you get

```
Thread[F[{{a,b},{c,d}}]]
```

Now this expression is subject to the same evaluation process. This means, first the head `Thread` is evaluated which stays the same. At this point the arguments are evaluated: Unfortunately, evaluating `F[{{a,b},{c,d}}]` is the same thing we started with and therefore it undergoes the same evaluation.

This leads to calling `F` over and over again until it is stopped by the `$RecursionLimit`. Your `F` never reaches the point where it is threaded over the list.

If you understood it so far, your first reaction might be: "but I don't want `Thread` to evaluate its argument". Then tell `Thread`, that it should hold it. The next is only for demonstration purpose! I'm using your original definition of `F`

```
ClearAll[F]

Unprotect[Thread];
SetAttributes[Thread, {HoldFirst, Protected}]

F[mat_] := If[mat[[0]] === List, Thread[F[mat]], f[mat]]
F[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]

(* {{f[a], f[b]}, {f[c], f[d]}} *)
```

A better way, to keep single arguments from evaluation is to use `Unevaluated` like shown in the comment of Leonid. With this you don't need to screw with built-in functions. First reset the attributes of `Thread`

```
Unprotect[Thread];
Attributes[Thread] = {Protected}
```

and then you can use the definition

```
F[mat_] := If[mat[[0]] === List, Thread[Unevaluated@F[mat]], f[mat]]
```

or you forget about this and stay with the `Listable` attribute which is shorter and faster in execution.

Comment: Nice answer.  You covered all facets. +1  Thanks for showing `Thread`/`Unevaluated` of which I am a fan.[(1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9862/121)[(2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16193/121)

Comment: @hairutan thank you very much for the detailed answer. You made it very clear.