# Function of Five Variables, and iterating over the last 3

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, evaluation

I have defined a function:

```
Y[k_, q_, {r_, θ_, ϕ_}] := SphericalHarmonicY[k, q, θ, ϕ]/r^(k + 1)
```

I have a list of coordinates `{r, θ, ϕ}`. I would like to keep `k` and `q` fixed, and evaluate the function over the list, but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: `k=some value1; q=some value2; Table[Y[k, q, {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}], {r, values}, {\[Theta], values}, {\[Phi], values}]`

Comment: `Y[kval,qval,Sequence@@#]&/@listOfTriples`, or if you really are inputting the triples as a list, `Y[kval,qval,#]&/@listOfTriples`.

Comment: Closely related, perhaps duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9861/121

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst =  {{r1, r2, r3}, {θ1, θ2, θ3}, {ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3}}

Thread[Y[k, q, lst]]
```

> {r1^(-1 - k) SphericalHarmonicY[k, q, θ1, ϕ1],
>       r2^(-1 - k) SphericalHarmonicY[k, q, θ2, ϕ2],
>       r3^(-1 - k) SphericalHarmonicY[k, q, θ3, ϕ3]}

Comment: FYI: I reversed my vote on this answer as I find it misleading.  Please see my rebutting answer.  Sorry for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Say that your input list looks like:

```
inputList = {{r1, θ1, ϕ1}, {r2, θ2, ϕ2}}

(* {{r1, θ1, ϕ1}, {r2, θ2, ϕ2}} *)
```

Then `Table` is a very easy way to produce the desired result

```
Table[Y[k, q, {inputs}], {inputs, inputList}]

(* {Y[k, q, {{r1, θ1, ϕ1}}], Y[k, q, {{r2, θ2, ϕ2}}]} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The right-hand-side of your function is already composed of [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) functions, therefore your code will work without any modification.  Please reference **Case #5** in [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica/7925#7925).

```
ClearAll[Y] (* no prior definitions *)

Y[k_, q_, {r_, θ_, ϕ_}] := SphericalHarmonicY[k, q, θ, ϕ]/r^(k + 1)

lst = {{r1, r2, r3}, {θ1, θ2, θ3}, {ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3}};

Y[k, q, lst]
```

> ```
> {r1^(-1 - k) SphericalHarmonicY[k, q, θ1, ϕ1], 
>  r2^(-1 - k) SphericalHarmonicY[k, q, θ2, ϕ2], 
>  r3^(-1 - k) SphericalHarmonicY[k, q, θ3, ϕ3]}
> ```

If the right-hand-side were *not* composed of `Listable` functions then the presently Accepted answer would not work anyway.  Observe:

```
Y2[k_, q_, {r_, θ_, ϕ_}] := bar[q, ϕ, foo[k, r, θ]]

Thread[Y2[k, q, lst]]
```

> ```
> {bar[q, ϕ1, foo[k, {r1, r2, r3}, {θ1, θ2, θ3}]], 
>  bar[q, ϕ2, foo[k, {r1, r2, r3}, {θ1, θ2, θ3}]], 
>  bar[q, ϕ3, foo[k, {r1, r2, r3}, {θ1, θ2, θ3}]]}
> ```

Note that only `bar` was Threaded over its arguments; `foo` remains undistributed.

To solve that case I prefer manual threading through a second definition using [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) to prevent premature evaluation:

```
Y2[k_, q_, sm : {_List, _List, _List}] := Thread @ Unevaluated @ Y2[k, q, sm]
```

Now:

```
Y2[k, q, lst]
```

> ```
> {bar[q, r3, foo[k, r1, r2]],
>  bar[q, θ3, foo[k, θ1, θ2]], 
>  bar[q, ϕ3, foo[k, ϕ1, ϕ2]]}
> ```

Note that you cannot do this externally (without the definition above) because `lst` is atomic within the unevaluated expression, therefore there is nothing to thread over:

```
ClearAll[Y2]

Y2[k_, q_, {r_, θ_, ϕ_}] := bar[q, ϕ, foo[k, r, θ]]

Thread @ Unevaluated @ Y2[k, q, lst]
```

> ```
> bar[q, {ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3}, foo[k, {r1, r2, r3}, {θ1, θ2, θ3}]]
> ```

To make that work you would need to insert the evaluated form of `lst` into the expression, e.g.:

```
With[{lst = lst},
  Thread @ Unevaluated @ Y2[k, q, lst]
]
```

> ```
> {bar[q, r3, foo[k, r1, r2]],
>  bar[q, θ3, foo[k, θ1, θ2]], 
>  bar[q, ϕ3, foo[k, ϕ1, ϕ2]]}
> ```

Reference:

- [Function in Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121)