# Creating a Block from a list of rules

Tags: function-construction, scoping

How can I create a function which works like `Block` but takes a list of rules as its first argument, rather than a list of assignments?

The function needs to be able to work with rules supplied either as an explicit list or via a symbol, and it should work when some of the symbols to be blocked have global values.

Test code:

```
a = 100;
code := a + b;
rules := {a -> 1, b -> 2};

(* using an explicit list of rules *)
ruleBlock[{a -> 1, b -> 2}, code]
(* 3 *)

(* using a symbol *)
ruleBlock[rules, code]
(* 3 *)

(* global values are unaffected *)
{a, b}
(* {100, b} *)
```

I have a working solution (below) but I have had to write separate functions for `List` and `Symbol` patterns, and I find the code a bit cumbersome. I would like to know if there is a simpler, cleaner way to write `ruleBlock`.

```
SetAttributes[ruleBlock, HoldAll]

ruleBlock[rules_List, code_] := 
 Replace[Apply[Set, Hold[rules], {2}], Hold[x_] :> Block[x, code]]

ruleBlock[rules_Symbol, code_] := 
 Replace[Apply[Set, OwnValues[rules] /. HoldPattern[{_ :> r_}] :> Hold[r], {2}], 
  Hold[x_] :> Block[x, code]]
```

Comment: You've got a bit of a problem in the case rules assigned to a symbol if the LHS of some of those rules already has a global value, as they will evaluate.  How do you want to handle that?

Comment: Oh, I see you're digging out `OwnValues`.  I forget who I'm talking to as most people wouldn't think to use `:=` to hold a list of values like this, but I would. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the rule list might also be defined with `=` *before* the global values are assigned. Ideally there wouldn't be any global values for the LHS of the rules, but I am working with a large body of code written by an incompetent fool (i.e. myself, several years ago...)

Comment: You made my profile quotes. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only alternative that comes to mind is to use [my `step` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121) to extract a definition rather than digging around in *Values lists; this has the advantage of being more robust as it will work with other kinds of definitions as well.

```
SetAttributes[ruleBlock, HoldAll]

ruleBlock[L_List, body_] := Block @@ Join[Apply[Set, Hold[L], {2}], Hold[body]]

ruleBlock[obj_, body_] := step[obj] /. _[x_] :> ruleBlock[x, body]
```

An extension you may wish to consider is handling for the undocumented `:=` syntax of `Block` which holds the RHS of assignments.  This adds considerable code length but also flexibility.  As above but with:

```
ruleBlock[L_List, body_] := Block @@ Join[
    Replace[Hold[L], {(a_ -> b_) :> (a = b), (a_ :> b_) :> (a := b)}, {2}],
    Hold[body]
  ]
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. Much more readable than mine, and as you say, more robust. I love the `Block @@ Join[Hold[x], Hold[y]]` construction - I always forget that `Join` works with any head.

Comment: @Simon You're welcome.  I wasn't sure if it would be useful to you.  I think I finally figured out what I was trying to do re: `:=`.   One remaining issue: `ruleBlock["null", code]` returns `"null"` because `"null"` is inert.  If you want the original expression returned you'll have to add a Condition.

Comment: Oh it's definitely useful. Another nice feature, I've just realised, is that if I have a chain of definitions like `r1:={a->1}; r2:=r1; r3:=r2` I can use `r3` and your code will recursively call `ruleBlock` until the symbol resolves to a list.

Comment: @Simon Yes, I should have explicitly stated that.  I used it for the that reason in [(19900)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19900/121).