# Reshaping associations, generalization of GroupBy

Tags: functions, associations, gathering

Let's say we have a set a\of associations:

```
dataset = {
  <|"type" -> "a", "subtype" -> "I", "value" -> 1|>,
  <|"type" -> "a", "subtype" -> "II", "value" -> 2|>,
  <|"type" -> "b", "subtype" -> "I", "value" -> 1|>,
  <|"type" -> "b", "subtype" -> "II", "value" -> 2|>
  }
```

where every entry is unique in terms of `{#type, #subtype}`,

#### I'd like to build a nested association for more handy querying, e.g. I would like to have:

```
nested["a", "II", "value"]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

#### I can start with

```
GroupBy[dataset, {#type &, #subtype &}]
```

> ```
> <|
>    "a" -> <|
>      "I" -> {<|"type" -> "a", "subtype" -> "I", "value" -> 1|>},
>      "II" -> {<|"type" -> "a", "subtype" -> "II", "value" -> 2|>}|>, 
>    "b" -> <|
>      "I" -> {<|"type" -> "b", "subtype" -> "I", "value" -> 3|>}, 
>      "II" -> {<|"type" -> "b", "subtype" -> "II", "value" -> 4|>}
> |>|>
> ```

But `nested["a", "I"]` points to a **list with one association**, what is expected but I would like to drop that list.

It seems that the third argument of `GroupBy` isn't generalized to handle nested grouping...

So basically I would like to have `... "I" -> <|"type" -> "a", ...`.

#### What is a generic way to go?

I can do:

- nested `GroupBy`:

  ```
  GroupBy[dataset, #type &, GroupBy[#, #subtype &, First] &]
  ```
- `Map` later:

  ```
  GroupBy[dataset, {#type &, #subtype &}] // Map[First, #, {-3}] &
  ```

But the first is not handy in general while the second is ugly (and not general either).

---

Acceptable outputs are:

```
<|
       "a" -> <|
         "I" -> <|"type" -> "a", "subtype" -> "I", "value" -> 1|>,
...
|>
```

or

```
<|
       "a" -> <|
         "I" -> <|"value" -> 1|>,

...
|>
```

or

```
<|
       "a" -> <|
         "I" -> 1 ,

...|>
```

but the first is the most desired one because we may have more that one ("value") key left.

Comment: What about something like `GroupBy[ dataset, {#type &, #subtype &}, Apply[ Association, #, 1 ] & ]`?

Comment: @gwr unfortunately, it is not general enough. We may have more levels, you can mimic it with: `GroupBy[dataset, {#type &, #subtype &, #type &, #subtype &}]`, now you would have to adjust *levelspec* of `Apply`, and using negative levels may be problematic because the input  may be more complex than a list of 1-lvl associations.

Comment: Did you note `GroupBy[ dataset, {#type, #subtype}& ]` which leads to a more controlled levelspec (this is also robust for your mimic extended case)? Maybe `nested[ {"a", "I" }, "value"]` is an option?

Comment: @gwr I didn't, this is quite nice. The "full nested" approach is "better" in that sense that you can still take `nested["a"]` or `nested[[All, "I"]]`.

Comment: Why is `GroupBy[dataset, {#type &, #subtype &}, Map[First]]` not suitable?

Comment: @J.M. because it won't work in general: `GroupBy[dataset, {#type &, #subtype &, #type &, #subtype &}]`. However, `GroupBy[dataset, {#type &, #subtype &, #type &, #subtype &}, 
 Map[f, #, {3}] &]` would be kind of ok, since 3 is 4-1 :P (take a look at gwr's answer)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One approach is to employ a helper function that unwraps singleton lists:

```
{delist[v_]} ^:= v
```

With this, the `GroupBy` expression is fairly succinct:

```
dataset // GroupBy[{#type&, #subtype& -> delist}]

(*
  <| "a" -> <| "I" -> <|"type" -> "a", "subtype" -> "I", "value" -> 1|>
             , "II" -> <|"type" -> "a", "subtype" -> "II", "value" -> 2|>
             |>
   , "b" -> <| "I" -> <|"type" -> "b", "subtype" -> "I", "value" -> 1|>
             , "II" -> <|"type" -> "b", "subtype" -> "II", "value" -> 2|>
             |>
   |>
*)
```

This generalizes to deeper nesting:

```
dataset // GroupBy[{#type&, #subtype&, #type&, #subtype& -> delist}]

(*
  <| "a" ->
      <| "I" -> <|"a" -> <|"I" -> <|"type" -> "a", "subtype" -> "I", "value" -> 1|>|>|>
       , "II" -> <|"a" -> <|"II" -> <|"type" -> "a", "subtype" -> "II", "value" -> 2|>|>|>
       |>
   , "b" ->
       <| "I" -> <|"b" -> <|"I" -> <|"type" -> "b", "subtype" -> "I", "value" -> 1|>|>|>
        , "II" -> <|"b" -> <|"II" -> <|"type" -> "b", "subtype" -> "II", "value" -> 2|>|>|>
        |>
   |>
*)
```

Comment: +1. A very nice appraoch that does beat applying `Association` at the right level.

Comment: @WReach, Another way to delist singletons (R.M. 2012)  list /. _[x_] :> x  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8790/built-in-way-to-de-list-singletons

Answer (score 10):

Instead of a nested association solution, would `Query` and `Select` be acceptable.

```
Query[Select[#type == "a" && #subtype == "I" &], "value"]@dataset

(* {1} *)
```

This form is more descriptive on what is happening and does not require reshaping of the list of associations.

If your data is such that there is only ever one item intersecting a particular `"type"` and `"subtype"` then tack on `First`.

```
First@Query[Select[#type == "a" && #subtype == "I" &], "value"]@
  dataset

(* 1 *)
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Extension**

You can extend this to a more general case in which you parametrise the filter by both key and value.

```
filterBy[filter_] := Function[Evaluate[And @@ ReleaseHold[Hold[Slot][First@#] == Last@# & /@ filter]]]
```

then with

```
target = {{"type", "a"}, {"subtype", "I"}};

Query[SelectFirst[filterBy[target]], "value"]@dataset

(* 1 *)
```

Comment: You might use [`SelectFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SelectFirst.html?q=SelectFirst).

Comment: This is a solution, but I really don't like `#type == "a"` such statements. The main point is the have compact and flexible solution. So once I have got my `nested`, it's easy to do many things with this.

Comment: @gwr Yes. That is a great addition. +1

Comment: @Kuba You can also go with `#["type"] == "a" && #["subtype"] == "I" &`. This gives additional flexibility as you can parametrise the selection by both key and value. For example `f[filterBy_] :=
 ReleaseHold[Hold[Slot][First@#] == Last@# & /@ filterBy]` then `And @@ f[{{"type", "a"}, {"subtype", "I"}}]` in the `Select`.

Answer (score 9):

I have posted code doing a very similar thing [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54493/81) - the functions `pushUp` and `pushUpNested`. That code was more general, since there I provided a declarative interface to group by values *or their parts*. To do what you need, I'll redefine slightly (assuming you run that code):

```
ClearAll[pushUpNested];
pushUpNested[{}, elemF_: Identity] := elemF;
pushUpNested[specs : {_List ..}, elemF_: Identity ] := 
   Composition[
     Map[pushUpNested[Rest[specs], elemF]], 
     pushUp@First[specs]
   ];
```

Now we create a transform:

```
transform = pushUpNested[{{"type"}, {"subtype"}}, First]


(* 
   Map[Map[First]@*GroupBy[#1[[Sequence[Key["subtype"]]]] &]]@*
   GroupBy[#1[[Sequence[Key["type"]]]] &]
*)
```

which we can now apply to get the nested structure:

```
nested = transform@dataset

(*

   <|
     "a" -> <|
       "I" -> <|"type" -> "a", "subtype" -> "I", "value" -> 1|>, 
       "II" -> <|"type" -> "a", "subtype" -> "II", "value" -> 2|>
     |>, 
     "b" -> <|
       "I" -> <|"type" -> "b", "subtype" -> "I", "value" -> 1|>, 
       "II" -> <|"type" -> "b", "subtype" -> "II", "value" -> 2|>
     |>
   |>

*)
```

The advantage of using `pushUpNested` is that it makes it very easy and declarative to construct such transforms, and the transform is available for inspection as a stand-alone fully-prepared function.

Comment: `pushUp` is needed too. Thanks, I've read your answer before, I just somehow forgot `pushUpNested` because I was able to do what I needed without additional functions. Now they seem inevitable.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, `pushUp` is needed, which is why I mentioned that I assumed you first run that code. I did use a (slightly more complex) version of `pushUpNested` for a real db with hundreds of thousands of entries, and it was a snap.

Comment: Is that intentional or is `GroupBy` not just finished? Because I have the latter impression. It allows nested grouping, yet the third argument can't handle it. It is so close to give me what I need :)

Comment: @Kuba I can't say for sure. You might be right. I will ask around when I get a chance.

Answer (score 6):

I believed this question to be a duplicate of [Create Nested List from tabular data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86578/121) and proposed, with minor variation, the same answer:

```
fn[x_List] := GroupBy[x, First -> Rest, fn]
fn[{a_}] := a

nested = fn[dataset]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> <|"I" -> <|"value" -> 1|>, "II" -> <|"value" -> 2|>|>, 
>  "b" -> <|"I" -> <|"value" -> 1|>, "II" -> <|"value" -> 2|>|>|>
> ```

```
nested["a", "II", "value"]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

WReach suggested a different reading of this question however.  To that end I propose:

```
ClearAll[fn]

fn[p_, r___][x_List] := GroupBy[x, Lookup[p] -> KeyDrop[p], fn[r]]
fn[][{x_}] := x

nested = dataset // fn["type", "subtype"]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> <|"I" -> <|"value" -> 1|>, "II" -> <|"value" -> 2|>|>, 
>   "b" -> <|"I" -> <|"value" -> 1|>, "II" -> <|"value" -> 2|>|>|>
> ```

```
nested["a", "II", "value"]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

Comment: I think that the associations in the source data introduce complexities that differentiate this question from the former one.  For example, care must be taken to deal with groups with single entries (e.g. try changing the type of the first entry from `"a"` to `"z"`).  Also, I got the impression that it was important to be able to specify the grouping keys explicitly rather than implicitly assuming that the data is to be grouped by the two left-most keys appearing in a fixed order in every entry.  Neither of these issues arise in the other question.

Comment: @WReach Does my update address your reading of this question?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the approach I would take to transform your dataset to a nested `Association`:

```
Clear[ makeNested ];
makeNested[ assoc_, keylist_] := GroupBy[
   assoc,
   keylist
 ] // Apply[
    Association,
    #,
    { Length @ keylist }
  ] &
```

Now `makeNested[ dataset, { #type &, #subtype &} ]` and

`makeNested[ dataset, { #type &, #subtype &, #type &, #subtype & } ]` will work as wanted.

For example:

```
(nested = makeNested[ dataset, { #type &, #subtype & } ]) // Dataset
```

[image: Nested Dataset]

```
nested["a","I","value"]
```

> 1

### Update: A more streamlined solution

Inspired by WReach's solution I tried to streamline this into a compact function that also get's rid of the keys that have already been used in the nesting. So here it is:

```
Clear[ formatLeaves ];
Options[ formatLeaves ] = {
   "DropKeys" -> None
};
formatLeaves/: List[ formatLeaves[ data_ ] ] := Module[
   {
      keys = OptionValue[ formatLeaves, "DropKeys" ]
   },
   KeyDrop[ data, keys ]
]

Clear[ makeNested ];
makeNested[ data_ , keylist_?(VectorQ[ #, StringQ ]&) ] := Module[
   {
      listKeys = Map[Key] @ keylist,
      lastKey
   },
   lastKey = Last @ listKeys;
   SetOptions[ formatLeaves, "DropKeys" -> listKeys ];
   GroupBy[
      data,
      ReplaceAll[
         listKeys,
         Rule[
            lastKey,
            lastKey -> formatLeaves
         ]
      ]
   ]
]
```

Now:

```
(nested = makeNested[ dataset, { "type", "subtype" } ]) // Dataset
```

[image: Cleaned up nested data]

```
nested[ "a","I","value" ]
```

> 1

Naturally this saves space in memory and on disk:

```
Map[ByteCount] @ { nested, dataset }
```

> {2064, 2280}

Comment: Nice, or even nicer: `GroupBy[assoc, keylist, Apply[# &, #, {Length@keylist - 1}] &]`.

Comment: Interestingly in the updated version `makeNested[ dataset, {"type", "subtype", "type", "subtype" } ]` will crash *Mathematica*. So no mimicing with this one. :-/

Comment: One might of course streamline `formatLeaves` as it may make sense to simply make the leaves `Datasets`. Also I find it quite annoying having to remember which functions accept `#key&` or `Key["key"]` or simply `"key"`- but hope for improvement never dies.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to retain the original keys, I'd be inclined to follow Edmund's answer; alternatively, if you are happy enough to throw away the keys (also given that "every entry is unique") one flexible approach follows a [nice solution of your own](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102483/2249).

```
 RecurAssocMerge[a : {__Association}] := Merge[a, RecurAssocMerge];
 RecurAssocMerge[a_] := Last[a];
 RecurAssocMerge[ini_Association, path_List, value_] := 
 RecurAssocMerge[{ini, Fold[<|#2 -> #|> &, value, Reverse@path]}];
 RecurAssocMerge[ini_Association, fullPath_List] := RecurAssocMerge[ini, Most@fullPath, Last@fullPath]; (* added from previous post to handle single list specification *)
```

Now build up incrementally after extracting values

```
Query[All, Values]@dataset // Fold[RecurAssocMerge, <||>, #] &

(* <|"a" -> <|"I" -> 1, "II" -> 2|>, "b" -> <|"I" -> 1, "II" -> 2|>|> *)
```